# Can't open /dev/input/js file descriptor after inotify event

Tags: c, linux, inotify, joystick, gamepad

I'm creating a Linux module for a game library that let's you hotplug multiple joysticks, it uses inotify to watch `/dev/input`.

I am testing it with 3 joysticks:

- First I connect 2 joysticks.
- Then I start the application, the joysticks work and I don't get a error.
- After that I connect the third joystick, `perror` gives: `/dev/input/js1: Permission denied`.
- When I check `ls -l /proc/<pid-of-process>/fd` it lists `/dev/input/js0` and `/dev/input/js2`.

All the joysticks work fine when I run it as root.

This is how it's initialized:

```
static void createGamepad(char *locName){
    char dirName[30];
    int fd;

    snprintf(dirName, 30, "/dev/input/%s", locName);

    fd = open(dirName, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK, 0);
    if(fd < 0){
        perror(dirName);
    }
}

struct dirent *dir;
DIR *d;
int i, notifyfd, watch;

// Attach notifications to check if a device connects/disconnects
notifyfd = inotify_init();

watch = inotify_add_watch(notifyfd, "/dev/input", IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);

d = opendir("/dev/input");

i = 0;
while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL){
    if(*dir->d_name == 'j' && *(dir->d_name + 1) == 's'){
        createGamepad(dir->d_name, i);
        i++;
    }
}

closedir(d);
```

After that inotify handles it like this in the `while(1)` loop:

```
static bool canReadINotify(){
    fd_set set;
    struct timeval timeout;

    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(notifyfd, &set);
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    return select(notifyfd + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout) > 0 && 
        FD_ISSET(notifyfd, &set);
 }

// Inside the event loop
struct inotify_event ne;

while(canReadINotify()){
    if(read(notifyfd, &ne, sizeof(struct inotify_event) + 16) >= 0){
        if(*ne.name != 'j' || *(ne.name + 1) != 's'){
            continue;
        }

        if(ne.mask & IN_CREATE){
            createGamepad(ne.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it even possible with inotify or should I use udev? And if it's possible, how can I solve this?

Comment: What are the file permissions on `/dev/input/js1` ? Is your user allowed to read from it ?

Comment: @nos `crw-rw-r--+ 1 root root`, and it has the same permissions as js0 and js2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very likely a race condition. You see, you get the inotify event when the device node is created (by udev using a `mknod()` call), but the access permissions are set by udev using a separate `chown()` call, just a tiny bit later.

See [systemd `src/udev/udev-node.c`, `node_permissions_apply()`](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev/udev-node.c). In this particular case, `/dev/input/jsX` is not a symlink, but the actual device node; at least with systemd the device node access mode gets set sometime later, after the actual node is created.

One robust solution would be to modify your `createGamepad()` function, so that instead of failing completely at `fd == -1 && errno == EACCES`, you instead retry after a short while; at least a few times, say for up to a second or two.

**However, [ninjalj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371250/ninjalj) pointed out a better suggestion**: use also the access permissions change as a trigger to check the device node. This is trivially accomplished, by using `IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE | IN_ATTRIBUTE` in the `inotify_add_watch()` function!

(You'll also want to ignore `open()==-1, errno==EACCES` errors in `createGamepad()`, as they are likely caused by this race condition, and the following `IN_ATTRIBUTE` inotify event will yield access to the same device.)

Prior to ninjalj's comment, I'd personally have used an array of input devices, and another for "possible" input devices that can/need to be retried after a short timeout to decide whether they are available or not, but I think his suggestion is much better.

Need/want an example?

Comment: Don't joystick device nodes get an IN_ATTRIB inotify event when their permissions change? If so, the OP could watch also for that event, no need for retrying.

Comment: @ninjalj: I checked, and indeed you do get the `IN_ATTRIB` inotify events. I think that should work just fine; excellent suggestion! motash, you only need to use `IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE | IN_ATTRIB` instead of `IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE`, and ignore `errno==EACCES` errors, to try ninjalj's suggested solution.

Comment: Thank you both, the `IN_ATTRIB` events work like a charm! If you could put it in an answer I can accept it and award the points.

Comment: @ninjalj: It was your idea; feel free to submit an answer to get the points!

Comment: @NominalAnimal: you diagnosed the problem. I merely suggested a possible improvement to your solution.

Comment: IN_ATTRIB doesn't produce any events with my testing.